# Can L'Hopital's rule be used when one of the limits is not defined?

Tags: calculus, limits

In my math textbook there's an example problem where you're asked to calculate
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left(x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}\right)$$
It says that the limit is of the form $1^{\infty}$ and that it can be transformed and solved using L'Hopital's rule.
The limit of $x$ is $1$, but the limit of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ isn't defined - the left limit is $-{\infty}$ and the right limit is ${\infty}$.
Why is it appropriate the use L'Hopital's rule here?

Comment: You are using l'Hopital on $\ln(x)/(1-x)$ for $x\to 1$, aren't you? So it's a $[0/0]$. For the interesting question of what to do for a situation where you have $[\text{foo}/\infty]$ as $x\to a^+$ and $[\text{oof}/(-\infty)]$ as $x\to a^-$, you can apply l'Hopital on the left, then on the right, and see if the limits match (provided they both exist in $\overline{\Bbb R}$).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes, I understand that, I am just confused about why they said it was a $1^{\infty}$ form.

Comment: Ah, it's those things. I'm not acquainted with the version (versions?) of l'Hopital for $f^g\to [1^\infty]$. I was only taught the $e^{g\log f}$ trick.

Comment: Try to solve by the formula for solving limits of the form of 1^{$\infty$}. That is e^[$$\lim_{x\to 1}$${g($x$)[f($x$)-1]]×$$\lim_{x\to 1}$$ f($x$). ; where f($x$)=$x$ and g($x$)=1$/$(1-$x$). Finally you will get the result of the above limit to be 1$/$e; where e is Euler's number.

Comment: Also you can solve the above limit by taking $ln$ on both sides. Let the above limit be L. Then $ln$L=($ln$$x$)$/$(1-$x$). Now you can apply L-Hopital's rule here. Finally you will get the result to be 1$/$e.

Comment: It just occurred to me That you can always claim that an indeterminat form $[1^{-\infty}]$ is an indeterminate form $[1^\infty]$ by considering $\lim (1/f)^{-g}$ instead of $\lim f^g$ (because if $f\to 1$ then obviously $1/f\to 1$).

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left(x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}\right){=\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}e^{\ln {\left(x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}\right)}}
\\=\exp\left({\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{\ln(x)}{(1-x)}}\right)\\=\exp\left({-\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{x}}\right)\quad [\text{by L'Hospital Rule}]\\=e^{-1}\\=\frac{1}e}$$

Answer (score -2):

$f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=e^{\frac{\ln x}{1-x}}$

Note $e^x$ is continuous. The composition of continuous functions is continuous and continuity preserves limits. Further in the proof for [l'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Cases_where_theorem_cannot_be_applied_(Necessity_of_conditions)), exceptions are made where the function is indeterminate regarding division by zero, continuity, and such.

There are often alternatives to l'Hopital's Rule that bypass the need to take a derivative.

Without taking the natural log, notice that for $x>1$, the base is greater than 1 and the exponent is negative, so the result is between $0$ and $1$. If $x<1$, the base is less than 1 and the exponent greater than 1, so again f(x) between $0$ and $1$. A sequence of $x$'s implies a bounded sequence for $f(x)$.

By the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, the sequence of values for $f(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Let $x_n=1+1/n$. Then $f(x_n)=(1+1/n)^{-n}$

Let $x_n=1-1/n$. Then $f(x_n)=(1-1/n)^{n}$

The limit of either as $n\to \infty =1/e$.

Consider $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. The function isn't defined at $x=0$, yet the limit exists.

$0<\sin x< x$

$0<1-\cos x< x$

Considering areas:

$\sin x\cos x<x <\tan x$

$\sin x \cos ^2 x < x\cos x < 
\sin x$

$x\cos x < \sin x < x$

$\cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x}<1$

So $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} =1$ by the squeeze theorem.

The definition of a limit allows for a function not to be defined where you are trying to find the limit. What matters is whether the function values stay close to some given value. And when they do, l'hopital's rule can help find that value, typically serving as a short cut to other approaches.

Comment: This post does not address the actual question, which is in what sense l'Hopital can be applied to the problem. More that half of your post does not even address $\lim_{x\to 1} x^{1/(1-x)}$, and the other part does not prove that the limit exists. (-1), but in all fairness I'd gladly make it (-10) if I could.